# Application in background and add to notification in specified time

Tags: android

I want write a program that when installed, runs in background and adds a notification at a specified time. How do I do this?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question shows no research, or work (code), or specific problems that need addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a really general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You're going to want to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) to run stuff in the background. In order to have something occur at a specific time, use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to fire off a broadcast. Then make you're own [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that receives the broadcast and adds a notification via the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).